Understanding of the AWS SQS visibility timeout
In my AWS infrastructure, I have an SQS queue and a Lambda function. The SQS queue has a visiblity timeout setting of 0, and no delivery delay, and a receiveMessageWaitTime of 0. The SQS queue has a DLQ with a max receive count of 2.  The Lambda function is consuming from the SQS queue using the AWS SDK's SQS client. There is only one instance of this lambda running, so it's concurrency is never greater than 1.  My most basic train of thought is that if there are 4 messages in the SQS queue, the following steps will happen in order:

The Lambda function creates a receiveMessage requests and polls for any messages in the SQS queue.
The Lambda function receives a response from SQS, which contains a number of messages.
The Lambda function processes these messages.
The Lambda function deletes each message based on the receipt handle.
Repeat step 1: poll the SQS queue again. Important: I assume that processed messages have been deleted and will no longer be visible.

In practice, this seems to work differently:

The Lambda function creates a receiveMessage requests and polls for any messages in the SQS queue.
The Lambda function receives a response from SQS, which contains a number of messages.
The Lambda function processes these messages.
The Lambda function deletes each message based on the receipt handle.
Repeat step 1: poll the SQS queue again. However, messages with the same message id but a different receipt handle are consumed. Additionally, the messages end up in the DLQ.

This seems to be caused by the visibility time-out, which I set to 0 (when I increase the value of this parameter, processing works as expected). However, I can't wrap my head around the following:
When I poll for messages, I get a specifc set of messages from SQS. Then, the polling stops. Before I poll again, I delete the processed messages. During a SINGLE poll (I perform long polling, 10 seconds), I get the same message with a different message receipt but the same message id twice or even more. What is the reason for this? I could imagine that while I am (still) polling, the message I already received from SQS becomes instantly available again and is received for a second time before the receiveRequest returns a response. I would like to get a deeper understanding of how this process works, especially with regards to the distributed nature of SQS.

How is your Lambda function accessing the SQS queue? Has the queue been configured as a Trigger for the Lambda function and the message is automatically passed to the Lambda function when it is invoked, or have you actually written code inside the Lambda function that calls ReceiveMessage() and DeleteMessage()?

I'm not using an event source but rather the AWS SDK to poll the SQS queue. I'm retrieving a number of messages at a time using ReceiveMessage(), and once I have processed them, delete them based on their receipt handle.

Okay. Please note that this means you will need to somehow trigger your Lambda function externally, rather than having the Lambda service automatically poll SQS and invoke the Lambda function when messages are available. Doing it via the Event Source has the other benefit that the Lambda service takes care of retrieving and deleting the message for you -- the Lambda function doesn't need to make any API calls to SQS. But, it's fine to do it the other way too.

Simple answer: You should set the Invisibility Timeout to several times the expected time that it will take to process the message.
Detailed answer: When a message is retrieved from an Amazon SQS queue, it is made invisible. This means the message will not be made available to any other consumer within that period. If the consumer fails, then the message will eventually reappear on the queue for re-processing (on the assumption that something failed). If, on the other hand, the consumer successfully deletes the message then it will be removed from the queue.
From Amazon SQS visibility timeout - Amazon Simple Queue Service:

Typically, you should set the visibility timeout to the maximum time that it takes your application to process and delete a message from the queue.

It makes no sense to set the Invisibility Timeout to zero, since it would cause exactly the problems that you are experiencing. It would be like calling the police whenever a teenager leaves home to immediately report them missing, rather than waiting to see whether they come home later in the day.
